# Is my usage of “go” here correct?

Tags: word-usage

When I ask for where a thing should be placed, I’ll say, “*where does this thing go?*”

When I’ve lost a thing, I’ll say, “*where has it gone?*” or “*where did it go?*”

Are my expressions natural in daily English?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, these are all correct and sound natural.

Even when the object cannot travel somewhere or move around on its own, it is natural to ask "Where did it go?" when it has been misplaced.